# Wordpress ACF Get Block Field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm running into an issue with ACF, and I just can't figure out what's going on, and nothing on the internet is helping out.
I've added some fields to the Image Slider block:
[image]

But no matter what I try inside of our custom block code: `image-slider.php` I cannot get the values of any of the `auto_play` fields. `get_field` always returns null. I know the value is there, because if I dump out `get_fields( $postID )`, I can see the `['page_builder'][2]` element has the value I want. I could get to it that way, but I can't seem to determine which index I'm on (the 2) programmatically.

So if you know either, how I can access the field directly, or figure out my current 'page_builder' index, that would be extremely helpful.

It's super confusing, because the `have_rows( 'slide_setting' )` call obviously knows where to look, and works as expected.

The custom block php looks like:

```php
<?php
    if(have_rows( 'slide_setting' ) ) {
        $digits = 3;
        $randID = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
        echo '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div id="swiper_'.$randID.'" class="col-md-12 wiche-swiper-top-navigation-wrapper">';
        echo '<div class="swiper-container wiche-swiper-top-navigation">';
        // var_dump( get_fields( get_the_ID() )['page_builder'][2] );
        // var_dump( get_post_field( 'auto_play' ) );
        // var_dump(get_field('image_slider_settings_auto_play'));
        // var_dump(get_row_index());
        // var_dump(get_field_objects( $post->ID ));
        // var_dump( get_row_index() );
        // var_dump( acf_get_field_group( 'slide_setting' ) );
        // die();
            if ( get_field( 'auto_play' ) ) {
                echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper" data-swiper-autoplay="' . get_field( 'auto_play_delay' ) . '" data-swiper-disable-on-interaction="' . get_field( 'auto_play_disable_on_interaction' ) . '">';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper">';
            }
                while( have_rows( 'slide_setting' ) ) {
                the_row();
                    $title = get_sub_field( 'title' );
                    $image = get_sub_field( 'image' );
                    $content = get_sub_field( 'content' );

                    if ( $image || $content ) {
                        echo '<div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide swiper-no-swiping">';
                            if ( $title ) {
                                echo '<div class="text-center slider-top-title">';
                                    echo $title;
                                echo '</div>';
                            }
                            if ( $image ) {
                                echo '<div class="banner-image">';
                                    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'full', '', array( 'loading' => false ) );
                                echo '</div>';
                            }

                            if ( $content ) {
                            echo '<div class="banner-content">';
                                echo $content;
                            echo '</div>';
                            }
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next-outsite">Next</div><div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-outsite">Prev</div>';
        echo '</div></div></div>';
    }
```

---

Comment: The problem is most likely `the_field()` - that is a function to `echo` out a particular field, which won't work if you are trying to determine a `true` or `false` value. Use `get_field('auto_play')` instead - as well as for your other `the_field()` functions for your auto play things - since you are essentially echoing an echo for the others.

Comment: You are partially correct (and thanks for responding) - I'm absolutely using the wrong function in the logic, but unfortunately I'm stuck even before we get there. When I `var_dump` `get_field('auto_play')` it outputs `NULL`. the ONLY way I've been able to successfully see the values of this block is by viewing ALL the blocks on the post via something like `var_dump( get_fields( get_the_ID() ) )` - which is only helpful if I can determine which block index I'm currently on.

Comment: Have you tried passing `get_the_ID()` to the `get_field('auto_play', get_the_ID()')`? Or you may consider getting the [block ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376416/is-there-a-php-function-that-will-return-the-block-id-generated-by-wordpress), to pass to the `get_field()` as well. You can check the if the block is a slider block first, and then get into `have_rows()`

Comment: I have tried the first - didn't help. I will look into the block_id solution - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping me out @disinfor - I ended up finding a solution (see answer below). I don't like it, but it covers what I need. I took a little inspiration from that 'block_ID' logic you pointed me to, but that particular implementation wouldn't have worked for me.

Comment: Glad you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get a perfect answer to my question, looks like the API to get what I want doesn't exist (dumb).

What I ended up with - I set up a new function in my theme's `functions.php` file that looks like the following:

```php
$post_slider_config_index = 0;

function get_the_slider_config( $post_id ) {
    global $post_slider_config_index;
    $page_builder = get_fields( $post_id )['page_builder'];
    $slider_config = null;
    foreach ($page_builder as $key => $value) {
        if ( $value['acf_fc_layout'] === 'image_slider_settings' ) {
            if ( $key > $post_slider_config_index ) {
                $slider_config = $value;
                $post_slider_config_index = $key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $slider_config;
}
```

And then inside my `image-slider.php` file I call it like so:

```php
$slider_config = get_the_slider_config( get_the_ID() );
if ( $slider_config[ 'auto_play' ] ) {
    echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper" data-swiper-autoplay="' . $slider_config[ 'auto_play_delay' ] . '" data-swiper-disable-on-interaction="' . $slider_config[ 'auto_play_disable_on_interaction' ] . '">';
} else {
    echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper">';
}
```

The `$post_slider_config_index` variable keeps track of the last index retrieved so that if there are multiple sliders on a page, it'll grab the right one as its rendered.

It's not perfect, it's not super efficient, but it does what I needed. Annoying WP doesn't just give you the information it obviously has already regarding where you are in the page.